# Java Spring boot app SSL issue with certificate and keystore

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https, keystore

I have an issue where a Spring Boot rest service application needs to run on HTTPS. This works fine locally with a self signed certificate added to my keystore.

When this is deployed to a production server and the live trusted signed cert added to the keystore on the production server the application fails to work on HTTPS. The application starts ok but going to the production URL on HTTPS returns no response.

Using openssl on the production server results in

openssl s_client -connect localhost:8888

CONNECTED(00000003)

### 140401679677256:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:

### no peer certificate available

### No client certificate CA names sent

### SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 263 bytes

New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE

### Expansion: NONE

I have no access to the production server.

Is there a way I can test with the live certificate and keystore locally and work out what the issue is? I can get a copy of the keystore from production just not access directly to the server.

Thanks.